# International transfer in Bangkok, flights on separate tickets: how to transfer luggage?

Tags: transit, luggage, international-travel, bkk

I'm traveling from China to Bangkok and taking another international flight on the same day four hours later from Bangkok to Delhi, but the two flights' tickets are booked separately.

How should I collect my luggage from Bangkok airport and drop it for Bangkok Delhi flight? Do I have to clear immigration first at Bangkok then collect my luggage from the belt and then check in for the Bangkok-Delhi flight, or there is an easier way?

Comment: What airline(s) are you flying on?

Comment: Air china & Thai airways

Answer (score 3):

Thai Airways and Air China are both in the Star Alliance. As such (and sometimes in other cases as well), you may be able to check your bag through at bag drop in China by showing your connecting ticket, although this is far from being a given (contact Air China if you want a definite answer). If this is available, you should be able to obtain your connecting boarding pass at the transfer desk in Bangkok Airport.

If this is not available, you will need to pick up your bag in Bangkok, clear Thai customs and immigration, check in again, and make your way through security to airside again. Four hours should be enough for this, but obviously you would want to avoid the hassle...